# Markov chains and boundary theory

Tags: markov-chains

In the next semester there is a reading called "Markov chains and boundary theory".
I have at least an imagination what a Markov chain is, but what is meant with boundary theory in this context?

Maybe you can give me a short impression what could be meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might correspond to the contents, and probably some extensions, of the seminal work by Kai Lai Chung [On the boundary theory for Markov chains](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812833860_0025), see also [there](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812833860_0028) for the second part.

See also Chung's [talk at ICM'70](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.2/Main/icm1970.2.0499.0506.ocr.pdf).

Comment: Hello downvoter...

Comment: Bye bye downvoter...